# Choose private field at runtime

Tags: javascript, private

With public field I can do so:

```js
class Smth {
  a = 0
  b = 0

  constructor(value, isA) {
    this[isA ? 'a' : 'b'] = value
  }
  
  toString() {
    return `(${this.a}, ${this.b})`
  }
}

console.log(new Smth(1, true) + "")
console.log(new Smth(2, false) + "")
```

What equivalent I can use for private field?

I see only solution with `eval`:

```js
class Smth {
  #a = 0
  #b = 0

  constructor(value, isA) {
    eval(`this.#${isA ? 'a' : 'b'} = value`)
  }
  
  toString() {
    return `(${this.#a}, ${this.#b})`
  }
}

console.log(new Smth(1, true) + "")
console.log(new Smth(2, false) + "")
```

or solution with full branching to `if`-`else`:

```js
class Smth {
  #a = 0
  #b = 0

  constructor(value, isA) {
    if (isA) {
      this.#a = value
    } else {
      this.#b = value
    }
  }
  
  toString() {
    return `(${this.#a}, ${this.#b})`
  }
}

console.log(new Smth(1, true) + "")
console.log(new Smth(2, false) + "")
```

Both solutions don't look nice for me.

---

If there is no such way, I'd like to know why.

That's clear that this['#x'] is an absolutely other thing. But there are plenty ways to express needed thing in other syntax like:

```
this.#[true ? 'x' : 'y']
this[true ? #x : #y]
this.#[true ? #x : #y]
this.#(true ? ##x : ##y)
```

and a lot other. Why not?

Comment: From the proposal: There are no private computed property names: `#foo` is a private identifier, and `#[foo]` is a syntax error [See](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-syntax). also more information: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/master/PRIVATE_SYNTAX_FAQ.md#why-doesnt-thisx-access-the-private-field-named-x-given-that-thisx-does

Answer (score 1):

[Source](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-syntax)

> There are no private computed property names: `#foo` is a private identifier, and `#[foo]` is a syntax error.

[Why doesn't `this['#x']` access the private field named `#x`, given that `this.#x` does?](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/master/PRIVATE_SYNTAX_FAQ.md#why-doesnt-thisx-access-the-private-field-named-x-given-that-thisx-does)

To get around this, you need to use an if/else statement and set each one in a non-dynamic way:

```js
class Smth {
  #a = 0
  #b = 0

  constructor(value, isA) {
    isA ? (this.#a = value) : (this.#b = value)
  }
  
  toString() {
    return `(${this.#a}, ${this.#b})`
  }
}

console.log(new Smth(1, true) + "")
console.log(new Smth(2, false) + "")
```

Comment: That's clear that `this['#x']` is an absolutely other thing. But there are plenty ways to express needed thing in other syntax like: `this.#[true ? 'x' : 'y']`, `this[true ? #x : #y]`, `this.#[true ? #x : #y]` `this.#(true ? ##x : ##y)` and a lot other. Why not?

Comment: @Qwertiy The reason is in the link that I shared **Dynamic access to private fields is contrary to the notion of 'private'.**

Comment: In C++ I can write `(true ? this.x : this.y) = 0;` but not in js :(